# directoryRoles returns Authorization_RequestDenied Even after successful authorization. Works on subsequent retry

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

My application accesses the `directoryRoles` resource via Microsoft Graph. This is done **immediately after** the Admin authorizes my client with the required scopes.

Usually, this flow works fine and calls to `/directoryRoles` returns a successful response. Intermittently, however, my application receives the following error:

```
{
  'error': {
    'innerError': {'date': '2020-02-18T20:06:49', 'request-id': <request_id>}, 
    'message': 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.', 
    'code': u'Authorization_RequestDenied'
  }
}
```

This happens even when the Admin has provided necessary authorization. I've also observed that in such cases, a retry after some time (say a min or two) returns success response.

1. Does this mean that it could take some random amount of time, spanning up to a minute or two, on the O365/Azure side to record the Admin's authorization for this resource?
2. Could there be some other explanation for such behavior?
3. Is retrying the API only solution in this case?
4. Would you have any other recommendations?

Appreciate any insight you could provide that would help me understand these intermittent errors.

Comment: I have tried and works fine, have you check the `application permission` which is `RoleManagement.Read.Directory, Directory.Read.All, RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory, Directory.ReadWrite.All`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the tenant's size and current load, it can sometimes take a moment or two for Azure AD to propagate consent for your application. This is normal and you should retry the request.

Comment: Thank you Marc. We have added retry logic and we will keep an eye on recurrence of this issue. We have experienced this with a tenant that had considerable number of accounts. So like you said, may be tenant size could play a role in the delay we experienced.